# Wrong namespace generation xmlns c#

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I use external library for creating soap messages between two services.
External library method for request:

```
public void CreateRequest(SecurityHeaderType securityHeader){}
```

SecurityHeader class:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
    public partial class SecurityHeaderType
    {
        private System.Xml.Linq.XElement[] anyField;

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute(Order=0)]
        public System.Xml.Linq.XElement[] Any
        {
            get
            {
                return this.anyField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.anyField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

I use it :

```
var secHeader = new SecurityHeaderType();
secHeader.Any = ....;
```

The problem is:
It generates wrong namespaces in soap message:

```
<h:Security xmlns:h="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

I need just one namespace:

```
xmlns:h
```

How could I fix it? Thanks